# How to click this , selenium

Tags: python, windows, selenium

So I need to click on this but no idea how, I tried xpath but its not working. I use python.

```
<input title-translate-context="info" class="flex subject no-outline ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" placeholder-translate-context ng-model="message.Subject" required placeholder ='Subject' title="Subject"
```

Comment: Can you please give more context and details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a rendered output in your browser, say Chrome, the easiest way would be open it in an inspector (right click -> inspect) then select Copy -> Copy as XPath (or copy selector if you prefer css selectors)

Comment: I did as you said but its still not working. thats the XPath I recived after clicking Copy As XPath '//*[@id="uid1"]/div[2]/div[5]/input'

Comment: Now Its working , I copy full XPath and its fine. I Always need to copy full XPath to make it work?